# bootstrap-multiselect creates button that does nothing, rather than dropdown multiselect list

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [bootstrap-multiselect](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/index.html#getting-started) to get a multi-select dropdown on my web page.

I've created a minimal example, the code of which is below. When I run this I get a single 'old-style' looking button on the page, which does nothing when it is clicked. I was expecting one of the bootstrap-multiselect dropdown multiselects.

[image]

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
        type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in versions you use.
Bootstrap is supported up to version 4 since they have [migration guide](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#migration) just up to v4

And also, as I can see, rawgit version that you use is not the same as the latest version.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dbnrf4av/) is the version that uses js and css from their page and it works fine.

If you need it to work with v5 then you can use it like this

```js
$('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
    buttonClass: 'form-select',
    templates: {
        button: '<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><span class="multiselect-selected-text"></span></button>',
    }
});
```

And you also need to use bundle version of bootstrap which contains popper.js

[Here is example](https://jsfiddle.net/dh23q9tx/)